# expo push notifications does not show in test flight

Tags: reactjs, react-native, push-notification, expo

I have expo react-native app. I added expo push notifications to it. I set it up following official guide and it shows `ExponentPushToken` correctly. When I try to send test notification by using [official service](https://expo.dev/notifications) I get it locally in expo go app on my iPhone. After deploying it to test flight `ExponentPushToken` changed so I tried to use it to push test notification to test flight version but I get this error:

`DeviceNotRegistered: "ExponentPushToken[token]" is not a registered push notification recipient`.

I changed push notifications in apple developer program:

[image]

I have only one identifier there.